# Using fibonacci and GoldenRatio not rounding correctly

Tags: c++, fibonacci

Not another Fibonacci question?

The codes works good for lower numbers but as I get higher in the sequence, the calculation goes out.  Can anyone see what I've done wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

/* 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610, 987, 1597,
 2584, 4181, 6765, 10946, 17711, 28657, 46368, 75025, 121393, 196418, 317811 */

int main()
{
const double goldenRatio = 1.618034;
const double oneMinusGoldenRatio = 1 - goldenRatio;
const float squareOfFive = sqrt(5);

double fib;
int result;

int testNumber = 10;

fib = (pow (goldenRatio,testNumber) - ( - (pow (oneMinusGoldenRatio, testNumber)))) / squareOfFive;

printf ("The Fibonacci sequence for %i equals %lf",testNumber,fib);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to floating point arithmetics :)

Comment: Hah! Are you doing this for [that Codewars kata](https://www.codewars.com/kata/52549d3e19453df56f0000fe/), too?

Comment: Your `goldenRatio` isn't very precise to start with. Why not calculate it using its formula, instead of using a literal value?

Comment: Not doing this for Codewars kata.  I'm just an old timer (51) trying to learn C++.  G. Sliepen, thank you, I will try that and see what happens.

Comment: It is time to read "What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating Point Arithmetic": https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: Picked a weird day to do it, Roofer. Fibonacci's been popping up a couple times an hour all afternoon. niamulbengali may just have unintentionally explained why.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have Binet's formula slightly wrong. I'm reading your code to be computing

`[phi^n - ( -((1-phi)^n) )] / sqrt(5)`.

This should be

`[phi^n - (-phi)^(-n)] / sqrt(5)`.

I think in your version if you omit the leading minus in `-((1-phi)^n)` then that is identical to `(-phi)^(-n)` because `1 - phi` equals `-(1/phi)` by definition of the golden ratio, but I may have gotten the algebra wrong there. In any case the following will print out the fibonacci values listed in the comment in your code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

/* 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610, 987, 1597,
 2584, 4181, 6765, 10946, 17711, 28657, 46368, 75025, 121393, 196418, 317811 */

double fibo(double n) {
    const double sqrtOfFive = std::sqrt(5.0);
    const double goldenRatio = (1.0 + sqrtOfFive) / 2.0;
    return (std::pow(goldenRatio, n) - ((std::pow(-goldenRatio, -n)))) / sqrtOfFive;
}

int main()
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= 28; i++) {
        std::cout << i << " => " << fibo(i) << "\n";
    }
}
```

Note though that, as others have said, floating point numbers have finite precision and finite bounds. When you deal with functions that grow exponentially fast you will overflow standard floating point types sooner than you might expect. Run the above with 28 increased above 30 to see what I mean.

This is just the nature of floating point arithmetic. [I discussed it more in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59434722/1413244).